# Terminal output of nested processes

Tags: python, linux, terminal, output, os.system

I'm using a series of nested python scripts to grid things in a particular way, some of which using proprietary software whose outputs I can't control (hence the clunky setup). When I call a script and try to write terminal output to file, e.g. `python pythonfile.py  >> output.txt` it only outputs the outermost level.

I tried to solve this by creating intermediate files in my subprocesses runs (i.e. having them run to `output_temp.txt` and then appending to the parent output file), it still doesn't capture the terminal output from the proprietary software where I don't have the ability to write to an output file.

Is there some top-level command to write all output from all levels of subprocess to file?

Comment: Can you show us the nesting of scripts?

Comment: If `>> output.txt` doesn't work, it may be that some of the subprocesses don't write their output to `stdout`, so unless they accept some kind of command-line arguments to do what you want, it may not be possible.

Comment: @r0xette: The parent script runs a for loop that iteratively calls pythonfile.py with string replacements `python pythonfile.py --var1=N --var2=N`. pythonfile.py then calls the proprietary code using mpi: `mpirun -np 1 ./mpifile ./input >> output.txt`. What seems to be the trouble is that running the compiled mpifile must also contain some further subprocess calls to terminal which I can't access, so the top level output is saved to output.txt, but not the subprocess outputs